# Ordenar objeto en js

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Estoy intentando ordenar un objeto en js, que va a ser usado para insertar diferentes `<option>` de un `<select>`, pero me sale el siguiente error

> Uncaught TypeError: data.sort is not a function

```js
var data = {
    10: "COLMENA",
    11: "CONJUNTO",
    12: "CONTENEDOR MET./MAD.",
    13: "ESTRUCTURA",
    14: "FUNDA",
    15: "INTERIOR",
    16: "KORRVU",
    17: "LAMINA",
    18: "LONA UBICADORA",
    19: "MOLDE IPK",
    20: "MULTIBOLSA",
    21: "PIEZA",
    22: "PLANCHA",
    23: "PROTO",
    24: "ROLLO",
};
data.sort();

console.log(data);

$.each(data, function (index, value) {
  $('.Format-Product').append('<option value="' + index + '">' + value + '</option>');
});
```

Comment: Lo que tienes no es un array, es un objeto. Si te fijas está entre llaves {} y no entre corchetes.

Comment: Tienes razón, ya corregí la pregunta

Comment: Tu variable `data` no es un `Array`, es un Objeto. Los objetos no implementan el método `sort()`. Debes convertir tu variable o usar una función de ordenamiento personalizada para tu objeto. Además, ¿qué tipo de ordenamiento quieres implementar? ¿Ascendente o descendente? Saludos

Answer (score 1):

Lo que he hecho  te ordena el objeto por el número, he añadido más elementos para la comprobación de que si lo ordena añadiendo en la parte posterior elementos con el número más bajo, esto te lo ordena de manera ascendente:

```
var data = {
   10: "COLMENA",
   11: "CONJUNTO",
   12: "CONTENEDOR MET./MAD.",
   13: "ESTRUCTURA",
   14: "FUNDA",
   15: "INTERIOR",
   16: "KORRVU",
   17: "LAMINA",
   18: "LONA UBICADORA",
   19: "MOLDE IPK",
   20: "MULTIBOLSA",
   21: "PIEZA",
   22: "PLANCHA",
   23: "PROTO",
   24: "ROLLO",
   09: "ZARRIBA",
   01: "Another one",
   2: "another",
};
var sortable = [];
for (var obj in data) {
   sortable.push([obj, data[obj]]);
}

sortable.sort(function(a, b) {
   return a[1] - b[1];
});
$.each(data, function (index, value) {
     $('.Format-Product').append('<option value="' + index + '">' + value + '</option>');
});
```

Espero te sirva.